# R: PCA - How to make a survey design object with svydesign

Tags: r, pca, survey

I am new to Principal Components Analysis in R. I'm currently working my way through a PCA with my own data, following this example: [PCA by Coreysparks](https://rpubs.com/corey_sparks/65532)

I'm stuck at the section which requires me to create a survey design object. This is my code:

```
options(survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")
scwb<-scwb[complete.cases(scwb),]
des<-svydesign(ids=~psu, strata=~ststr, weights=~cntywt, data=scwb , nest=T)
```

I then receive the following message -

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'psu' not found
```

I tried substituting `psu` with `1` , since I'm pretty sure I'm working with Simple Random Sampling. But then the error message points out `object 'ststr' not found` and I assume it's the same for `cntywt`.
I've been working on this for a couple of hours and I simply can't figure out (even after quite some research) how to properly fill out this function so that I can continue with the PCA.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem?

EDIT: Here is a sample of my data:

```
  IDN

 Jobsat_1 Jobsat_2 Jobsat_3 Member_1 Member_2 Member_4 LingInt Belong_2 Belong_3 Grpor_14 Ethnic10 MEDIAb Trust_G1 Trust_G2
1       10       10        8        3        1        1       5       10       10        2        1      2        1        3
2        7        7        5        4        1        1       5       10       10        4        4      2        3        3
3        7        7        7        1        1        1       5        9       10        4        3      2        1        1
4        7        7        7        2        1        1       5       10       10        3        3      2        3        3
5        7        8        8        3        3        3       5       10        8        3        4      2        3        3
6        7        7        7        2        1        2       5       10        8        4        3      2        5        3
  Grpor_3 Grpor_4 Grpor_12 Emp_1 Volas_10 Mstatus1 Child_1 Health_1 YRBIRTH Rgender Brthcoun YR_IMM Relig_2 Educ_R INCOM_14
1       1       5        2     3       15        0       0        2      31       1        1    100       3      4       73
2       7       6        9     2       15        1       5        1      40       2        1    100       7      8      105
3       5       5        7     1       10        1       3        3      60       1        1    100       4      3       40
4       8       8        8     3        4        1       4        2      63       1        1    100       2      3       30
5       5       4        8     2       20        1       0        2      37       2        1    100       3      8       60
6       7       7       10     2       20        1       1        2      37       2        1    100       6      8       73
  Emp_1.1        pc1        pc2        pc3        pc4         pc5        pc6       pc7         pc8         pc9       pc10
1       3  1.9148465  4.9846483 -0.8072519 -3.3183158 -3.32593626 -0.8836492 0.4113892  1.26298570 -0.32539801  1.4829219
2       2 -0.8358479 -0.3853229 -2.4203323  0.2514915 -0.08298205 -0.8393284 0.2384652 -0.04452874 -0.76024480  3.0219680
3       1  0.5800140  1.3872784 -3.8136358 -1.4466660  0.49100339  1.0119573 0.3198218 -0.27307314 -1.46013793 -0.7989148
4       3 -1.0482772  0.4416652 -2.7239398 -2.0870089 -1.23500720 -1.6997003 0.2737917  0.76019756 -1.41174450  0.2476696
5       2  0.1772093  0.7945494  0.3299359  0.7466387 -0.37083214 -0.2998434 0.4494944 -0.04000732 -0.09798538 -0.1694823
6       2 -1.5970861 -0.3793862 -2.0577713 -1.2681369  0.02748217 -0.8220763 0.1409177 -0.15252729 -1.15142836 -0.2362450
         pc11       pc12        pc13
1 -0.06980251  0.6393237 -0.66798274
2 -0.39774429 -0.1281088 -0.06633185
3  0.33557364  0.4008058 -1.13155741
4  0.07448897 -0.5383089 -0.02582100
5 -0.04507346 -0.1805617  1.42605349
6 -0.06659864  1.1336526  0.04854108
```

Comment: Please show us some example data.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Martin - please see edit

Comment: I'm not familiar with PCA. But there is no column `psu` in your data. I believe this causes your error message.

Comment: an SRS design would be `des <- svydesign( ~ 1 , data = yourdata )` but if your data isn't a complex survey and doesn't have weights, not sure if using `library(survey)` makes sense for your analysis?

Comment: Hello Anthony - so you're saying that if I don't have weights in the data (which I don't) that doing a PCA would not make any sense?